# Cannot create DocumentFragment storing td, tr or th?

Tags: javascript, html, documentfragment, html5-template

Is it possible to have DocumentFragments contain tr, th or td tags?

If I do this:

```
var template = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        '<table></table>'
    );

    console.log(template.childNodes);
```

I get the output of `[table]`.

If I do this:

```
var template = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        '<td></td>'
    );

    console.log(template.childNodes);
```

I get the output of `[]`!!!?!?

If I do this:

```
var template = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        '<td><p></p></td>'
    );

    console.log(template.childNodes);
```

I get `[p]`??!?!?!??!?!??!

And finally if I do this:

```
var template = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        '<span><td></td></span>'
    );

    console.log(template.childNodes);
```

I get `[span]` - where's the td gone??!

I don't understand the inconsistency here. Is it possible for document fragments to only hold certain elements? What I would like to do is do something akin to the second this above, and then retrieve the td using `querySelector`.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `document.createRange()…` and not just `document.createDocumentFragment()`? The later can contain just `<td>`s perfectly well.

Comment: I wasn't awRe there was a difference to be honest.. I was using the former to allow me to specify xhtml direct. Is there a way of doing that with the latter method?

Comment: @Matijs I just tried it with createDocumentFragment() and get the same result...

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1**

Use [createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment), create a `<td>` element, and add it to the DocumentFragment with `appendChild()`:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
frag.appendChild( document.createElement( 'td' ) )
console.log( frag.childNodes )  // output => [td]
```

**Solution 2**

Create a `<template>` element, add HTML content to `innerHTML`, then get the DocumentFragment from the `content` property:

```
var template = document.createElement( 'template' )
template.innerHTML = '<td></td>'
var frag = template.content
console.log( frag.childNodes )   // output => [td]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a library for doing just this (creating document fragments from an HTML string). It is called [`html-fragment`](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/html-fragment).

This small library attempts to use the range API (as you are doing), but if the top level node is a node that needs a specific parent node (such as a `td`), it will attempt to try some other solutions, such as a `template` if it is supported, otherwise it does it the "old fashioned way" where it wraps it first with the correct parent tag, and then adds the nodes you wanted to the document fragment (without the temporary parent nodes).

You would use it like so:

```js
var html = '<td><p>Hello World</p></td>';
var fragment = HtmlFragment(html);

console.log(fragment.firstChild) //td
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-fragment@1.1.0/lib/html-fragment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const range = new Range()
const tableRange = new Range()

const table = document.createElement('table')
const tbody = document.createElement('tbody')
const tr = document.createElement('tr')
const colgroup = document.createElement('colgroup')

/**
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Table_content
 */
const tableTags = [
  'tbody',
  'thead',
  'tfoot',
  'caption',
  'colgroup',
  'col',
  'tr',
  'td',
  'th'
]


export function createFragment(str: string) {
  const firstTag = str.match(/^<(([a-z]|-)+)/)?.[1]
  if (firstTag && tableTags.includes(firstTag)) {
    switch (firstTag) {
      case 'tbody':
      case 'thead':
      case 'tfoot':
      case 'caption':
      case 'colgroup':
        tableRange.selectNodeContents(table)
        break
      case 'tr':
        tableRange.selectNodeContents(tbody)
        break
      case 'td':
      case 'th':
        tableRange.selectNodeContents(tr)
        break
      case 'col':
        tableRange.selectNodeContents(colgroup)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
    return tableRange.createContextualFragment(str)
  }
  return range.createContextualFragment(str)
}
```